# Error: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ xenial \ stable' invalid

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, docker

I was following instructions (https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1) to try install Docker CE on VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16.04.3.  Then when I tried to set up the stable repository on step 4 by doing:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

I got

```
Error: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ xenial \ stable' invalid
```

Can someone clarify what the error means / how to fix it?  I am new to programming but online search doesn't appear to show anything directly relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That command is incorrectly line-wrapped which introduces line breaks and backslash characters where there should be none. The correct command would be:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

However, you still need to find and remove the previously added bogus entries. One way to find the files is via `grep`:

```sh
grep -ne '^deb.*docker.*\\' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}
```

I assume you know how to edit or remove files owned by `root`.

Comment: I started a new virtual machine and its now working!

Comment: Sad there is actually a question on this.

Comment: I don't think that it would get added if an error occur. At least, in my case, I don't see anything that already got installed (and I don't have `'\'`s in my case, still wondering what's wrong).

Answer (score 5):

check the file at /etc/apt/sources.list. The repo line should read:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
```

Note the lack of backslash. You will need root privileges in order to edit this file if it is incorrect.

Comment: Corrected, THX!

Answer (score -2):

```
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
```

this erred for my CICD with -- *deb invalid.*

Then changed to:

```
add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable'
```

worked for me (that is, changed " to ').

Comment: There is nothing in the quoted portion that would be treated differently with the different quotes. Perhaps when you used double quotes they were not standard double quotes, but fancy ones (i.e. a different unicode character) copy-pasted from somewhere?

Comment: @Zanna If it is really through CICD, then maybe there is a re-write somewhere before the line gets used. I've seen such issues many times. Although that still doesn't answer the question since the issue in the question was the `'\'` and not the quotes.